# Add WAR to spring-boot-web Jetty instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty-9

I have two applications: A simple spring-boot-web application running my stack as a standalone jar, and a separate web application built as a war.

I want to "run/deploy/execute/whatever we call it" the war file in the spring-boot application from code. Under normal circumstances, I would have created a WebAppContext and set the war property. Unfortunately, this has no effect from within a spring-boot-web app.

I want the existing war file to live next to the jar file and be loaded on demand from code when needed.

Comment: I would vote against this requirement.  Spring Boot executable requires a main, yml, and JAR packaging; WAR file packaging is different and does not include the main.  I deploy a Spring Boot to JBOSS as a WAR.  On the day I get to leave JBOSS behind I have to modify the app to add the main and yml and change the packaging.  It should be one or the other, not both.

Comment: @duffymo You're missing the point. This has nothing to do with packaging. This is about adding an existing WAR file to an existing embedded Jetty instance started by spring-boot-web.

Comment: Makes no sense to me.  I'd deploy them separately.